# How to resize QGraphicsTextItem and adjust the contents size?

Tags: qt

I have a `QGraphicsTextItem` in `QGraphicsScene`. What I want to implement is to resize the size of `QGraphicsTextItem` with mouse and the size of contents can adjust itself.
BTW, can `QGraphicsTextItem` be rotatable?

Comment: Regarding item rotation please see [`QGraphicsItem::setRotation`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation), [`QGraphicsItem::setTransform`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransform) etc.

Comment: What do you mean by adjust the contents size? Increase/decrease font size?

Comment: To thuga: Yes, that is.

Comment: Well the resizing part is pretty straight forward. You just listen to the mouse events and react accordingly. You can create your own size grip by subclassing `QGraphicsItem` and setting a parent to it. Then when you drag it, you adjust the size of the parent.

Comment: I solved it yesterday, thanks.